# choose all images (*.jpeg) from Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a project in my class to make image viewer and hide selected images in C#.

I want to search all images(.jpeg) on windows phone 7 & display it in in a Listbox with images  stack panel.

Can say an image gallery & after selecting multiple images have to store it in isolated storage.

I figured that since I don't have windows phone don't know how are folders & drive structure in windows phone is it like our windows xp or 7 C: drive as phone memory and D: drive as memory card as in android which have partitions for user data, systems, cache?

Sorry if question is misunderstand 
want to retrieve all images from device to a list box containing image 
Have  two list box scrolling images vertically

List Box 1

```
MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
            var pictures = mediaLibrary.Pictures;
            foreach (var picture in pictures)
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(picture.GetImage());
                MediaImage mediaImage = new MediaImage();
                mediaImage.ImageFile = image;
                lstImages.Items.Add(mediaImage);
            }
```

Then
on selectionchanged event of list box 1 
want to select image / images and move that image to list box 2 one by one
which will be used to store in an isolated storage or anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Windows Phone will not expose any file system to you. Windows Phone has something called tasks.

Tasks are divided into launchers and choosers.

What you need to use is called **PhotoChooserTask**

Check this link;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394019%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

However, it won't give you multiple files at once.

By the way, you can always run with the Windows Phone Emulator included in the SDK. No need to have a physical device.

Comment: thanks Adrian , but i want to access multiple images after searching google found that it is possible using list box haven't used that method though, the aboive code displays images scrolling vertically whenver i tap on an image that image goes to second listbox and whenever i tap second image it adds to the listbox , and goes on.     and that selected images in second list box will gets stored in isolated storage or encrypted. any help will be appreciated        Thanks

Comment: Hi, any solution for displaying and selecting multiple images?

Comment: @AlanFeng, well, you can use the MediaLibrary class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx like in the example above, and use the GridMode of the LongListMultiSelector of the WPToolkit. http://phone.codeplex.com/ See this video in minute 5:20, has exactly what you are looking for. http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-31-Multiple-Selection-with-the-LongListMultiSelector